# How to pass javascript variable to velocity template

Tags: spring, templates, velocity, jqwidget

I created a dropdownlist using jqwidgets and i got a form using velocity template. In the form action i want to get the selected value of my dropdownlist. i need the value in my controller page. How can i get the selected value of the dropdownlist inside velocity template variable? I am passing the item inside $submitUrl.setParameter("filePath", "item"). but if I print the value inside controller then I am getting only item. not the selected value of the dropdownlist. Any suggession?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () 
        {

            // Create the countryjqxWidget DropDownList
            $("#countryjqxWidget").jqxDropDownList({source: countryList, selectedIndex: 0, width: '200', height: '25', theme: 'ui-redmond'}); 


            $('#countryjqxWidget').on('change', function (event)
            {     
                var args = event.args;
                if (args) {
                // index represents the item's index.                      
                var index = args.index;
                var item = args.item;
                // get item's label and value.
                var label = item.label;
                var value = item.value;
                alert(value);
               var item = $("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList('getSelectedItem');

            } 
            });



         });
</script> 

<form id="form" class="form-horizontal"  action="$submitUrl" method="post" >            
            #lr_btn("submit-btn", "Submit", "Submitting...")
    </form>  



#set( $submitUrl = $renderResponse.createActionURL() )
$submitUrl.setParameter("submit", "upload")
$submitUrl.setParameter("filePath", "item")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried by adding the "countryjqxWidget" within your Form and setting its "name" attribute. As far as I know, if you set the "name" attribute, the selected value will be passed automatically on Form submit. It does not matter that the jQWidgets [DropDownList](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdropdownlist/index.htm) is created from DIV tag,  You can still set its "name" attribute.